# Postgresql, output result from select with +1 hour

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following `SQL` which works for `GROUP BY` the hour:

```
SELECT
CONCAT(TO_CHAR(timestamp::timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH'), ':00:00') as time_from,
car_id,
SUM(km) as driven from car_data
group by TO_CHAR(timestamp::timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH'), car_id
order by time_from, car_id;
```

I would like an extra output, which is `time_from` +1 hour interval.
I've tried with:

```
SELECT
CONCAT(TO_CHAR(timestamp::timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH'), ':00:00') as time_from,
CONCAT(TO_CHAR(timestamp::timestamp + interval '1 hour', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH'), ':00:00') as time_to,
car_id,
SUM(km) as driven from car_data
group by TO_CHAR(timestamp::timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH'), car_id
order by time_from, car_id;
```

But that reports I need to `GROUP BY` that field also:

```
ERROR:  column "car_data.time" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

, which I do not wish to do. How can I best archive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add the two columns to the `group by`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(TO_CHAR(timestamp::timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH'), ':00:00') as time_from,
       CONCAT(TO_CHAR(timestamp::timestamp + interval '1 hour', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH'), ':00:00') as time_to,
       car_id,
       SUM(km) as driven 
FROM car_data
GROUP BY time_from, time_to, car_id 
ORDER BY time_from, car_id;
```

However, I would not convert the timestamps to strings.  Instead, use `date_trunc()`:

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', timestamp::timestamp) as time_from,
       date_trunc('hour', timestamp::timestamp) + interval '1 hour' as time_to,
       car_id,
       SUM(km) as driven 
FROM car_data
GROUP BY date_trunc('hour', timestamp::timestamp), car_id 
ORDER BY time_from, car_id;
```

Comment: `date_trunc('hour', timestamp::timestamp)` gives me multiple results within the same hour.

Comment: @AlfredBalle . . . Are you sure you are aggregating by `date_trunc('hour', timestamp::timestamp)`?  You should get multiple results -- but only for multiple `car_id`s.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to place your current working query into a CTE, and then to use that to generate the output you want:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        timestamp::timestamp AS time_from,
        car_id,
        SUM(km) AS driven
    FROM car_data
    GROUP BY timestamp::timestamp, car_id
)

SELECT
    CONCAT(TO_CHAR(time_from, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH'), ':00:00') AS time_from,
    CONCAT(TO_CHAR(time_from + interval '1 hour', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH'), ':00:00') AS time_to,
    car_id,
    driven
FROM cte
ORDER BY
    time_from, car_id;
```